# Align text to bottom of bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'd like to have some text align to the bottom of panel-content in a [bootstrap panel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#panels). (I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7) However, using

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

aligns it to the bottom of the whole panel -- which is in the footer. I'd like it to just align to the bottom of the panel-content div. But I can't figure out why it's doing this.

Below is an image of what's going on, and then my code for both the panel divs and the styling for the 'save'. I'm trying aligning 'save' to the bottom of the panel-content div, but it enters the footer.

[image]

```
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body editdiv my-textarea" contenteditable>
          Panel content
          <p class="savemet bottom">save</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <input type="text" class="poetic" placeholder="e.g. jealousy or loss">
          <div class="idea"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

...

```
  .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please include your markup for the panel and contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `position: absolute`

> An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position value is absolute or fixed. The top, right, bottom, and left properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing block. (**The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.**).

So you need to put `position: relative` to your `panel-content` div.

Comment: Thanks for sending me to the docs. Unfortunately, setting `position: relative` to the `panel-content` div doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: You can decide yourself the *containing* block. It's usually the parent, or the block that you want your element to be positioned *relatively* to. Have you tried, e.g. `bottom: 100px` instead of setting it to 0?

Comment: Oh! Actually you're right, once I set `panel-body` to `position: relative` it worked -- I had thought the class was `panel-content` and that's why it didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the panel content div a position of relative, and then give the item you are trying to place on the bottom absolute positioning and place that div or element within the panel content div.